# Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006

Tags: c#, msbuild, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm trying to release a Xamarin.Forms application, but when I change to release in the configuration  for the Android project and build I get the following error:

```
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Int32 Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Resource/String::ApplicationName' (defined in assembly 'Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.Android, Version=13.2451.0.29, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Int32 Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Resource/String::ApplicationName
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
       at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
       at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
       at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() XamarinCRM.Android
```

Answer (score 4):

The same error message occurred with me. I was able to solve it like this:
Right-click the **Android Project > Properties > Android Options > Linker**, and then choose the "None" option in the **Linking** property.

Comment: this is not a solution. xamarin linker is there for a purpose and you need to resolve the error, not skip it.

Comment: This is a bandage not a fix.

Answer (score 1):

We suspect that there are some version conflicts between **Syncfusion/Xamarin.Forms assemblies** and we kindly request you to follow the below steps.

1. Update your **Essential Studio for Xamarin** to latest version **(15.1.0.41)** which can be downloaded from the following location.

   **Link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/version-history/15_1_0_41
2. Update your Xamarin.Forms version to 2.3.3.180.

Please get back to us if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.